# Rewind Remote Branch

Tags: git

We have the following git tree structure:

```
Local Working Branch A ---> Remote Working Branch A
                                \
                                 \
 -------------            Remote Main Branch
                                 /
                                /  
Local Working Branch B ---> Remote Working Branch B
```

And to make sure things are working before they go into the main branch, we follow this procedure:

```
checkout main
Pull main
checkout working A
merge main
push working A
```

We then test, then

```
checkout main
merge working A
push main
```

The problem is A bug was missed when addressing merge conflicts, and during the test, but it contains a fair amount of code from branch B. If I revert, that makes an commit that overwrites those changes, but I don't want to overwrite Branch B's changes that were merged in, I want to rewind remote branch A and local branch a before the main branch was merged in, and fix code pre-main-merge.

So revert doesn't work for me, and I don't know what the best way to reset or rewind or rebase (and don't know which is better) for a remote working branch in this scenario.

Comment: This is a pretty good description of why `rebase` is better than `merge main`.

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: `rebase` takes your whole branch history and rewrites it as though it started from the new "base" that you specify. In this way, all of branch B would be in the past before the first commit from branch A. This would allow you to deal with your issue without having to consider branch B context separate from "main".

Answer (score 0):

After researching several options, each getting more convoluted, had an "aha" moment. The easiest was simply to make a new branch based off the old revision.

```
git branch workingAVersionB [Hash23523something]
git checkout workingAVersionB
git push origin workingAVersionB
```

And then continue on with life as desired.